# std::algorithm to make this more expressive

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, std

I'm working on my own blockchain implementation in C++17.

To learn as much as possible, I would like to reduce loops as least as possible, moving to the alternative (and more expressive) loops within the std::algorithm library.

In a nullshell, within the Blockchain algorithm, each block contains it's own hash and the hash of the previous block (except the **Genesis-Block** which doesn't contain a previous block [first in the container]).

I want to implement a **Validate** function in the Blockchain object that takes pairs of blocks (which are contained in a std::vector), and checks the hashes (and previous hashes) to make sure they haven't been tampered with.

Current code (works):

```cpp
bool Blockchain::Validate() const
{
    // HASH is in ASCII
    std::array<unsigned char, 64> calculated_hash{};

    // No underflow here since Genesis-Block is created in the CTOR
    for (auto index = this->chain_.size() - 1; index > 0; --index)
    {
        const auto& current_block{this->chain_[index]};
        const auto& previous_block{this->chain_[index - 1]};

        SHA256{previous_block}.FillHash(calculated_hash);

        if (!std::equal(std::begin(calculated_hash), std::end(calculated_hash),
                        std::begin(current_block.GetPreviousHash()), std::end(current_block.GetPreviousHash())))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I would like to know if there's an algorithm that works somehow the way Python does its ", ".join(arr) for strings, which appends commas between each adjacent pair in the array, but instead will check until a certain condition returns false in which case stops running.

TLDR:

If this is my container:
A B C D E F G

I would like to know if theres an algorithm that asserts a condition in adjacent pairs: (A, B), (B, C), (C, D), (D, E), (E, F), (F, G)

And will stop if a condition has failed, for example:

A with B -> True

B with C -> True

C with D -> **False**

So the algorithm will return false. (Sounds like an adjacent implementation of std::all_of).

Does a std::algorithm like this exist? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a `std::adjacent_find`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some range `v` where you want to check each adjacent element for some condition, and return early, you can use [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

First write a lambda that compares adjacent elements:

```
auto comp = [](auto left, auto right)
{
  return // the Negation of the actual condition
}
```

Note that the negation is needed, so that you return early when you reach the actual `false` case. So in your case, `A,B` and `B,C` would compare `false`, and `C,D` would compare true.

Now you can use the lambda like this:

```
return std::adjacent_find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), comp) == std::end(v);
```

---

In your manual loop, you actually appear to be iterating in reverse, in which case you can write:

```
return std::adjacent_find(std::rbegin(v), std::rend(v), comp) == std::rend(v);
```

Comment: Well, I tried using it in the beginning, but the negate killed me until this comment.
This works for me, thanks!

Comment: @NoamRodrik Yes, the negation of the result in the lambda is very important. Glad it makes sense.